# Date format issue on admin pannel

Tags: php, magento

I have a website on magento framework. When i logged in admin panel click on `Customer > Manage customer` then all the customer detail are showing with ( `Name, Email, Avtar, Group Phone No , ZIP, Country, State, Customer since, Action` )

When user sign up on `2 OCT 2015` then the date is showing in `Customer since` is  `Feb, 10,2015`. It is picking month as a date and date as a month.

Will you please tell me how can i change the format of Customer Since tab

Comment: Please give me response on this issue

Answer (score 0):

try this

magento have date format in `app/code/core/Mage/core/Model/Date.php` file. if you want to change in format you can do that by overriding the model.

> **Note : never modify core files**

I closely looking the issue and found that your `month` and `date` are swapping with each other.

try this

You can copy the file to `\app\code\local\Mage\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Backend\Time\Created.php` and modify the functions necessary, once modified and uploaded it will take precedence over the core file and no worries about being overwritten during an update (though, if they update and that file is part of it, I would hope it would be to fix the problem)

the update to that file is here, so nobody needs to hop pages to find it

Replace `beforeSave` with this:

```
public function beforeSave($object)
{
    $attributeCode = $this->getAttribute()->getAttributeCode();
    $date = $object->getData($attributeCode);
    if (is_null($date)) {
        if ($object->isObjectNew()) {
            $object->setData($attributeCode, Varien_Date::now());
        }
    } else {
        // ADD THIS
        $date = strtotime($date);

        // convert to UTC
        $zendDate = Mage::app()->getLocale()->utcDate(null, $date, true, $this->_getFormat($date));
        $object->setData($attributeCode, $zendDate->getIso());
    }

    return $this;
}
```

This also needs to be corrected on the way out of the database. Replace `afterLoad` with this:

```
public function afterLoad($object)
{
    $attributeCode = $this->getAttribute()->getAttributeCode();
    $date = $object->getData($attributeCode);

    // ADD THIS
    if (!is_null($date)) {
        $date = strtotime($date);
    }

    $zendDate = Mage::app()->getLocale()->storeDate(null, $date, true, $this->_getFormat($date));
    $object->setData($attributeCode, $zendDate->getIso());

    parent::afterLoad($object);

    return $this;
}
```

I think this might help you.

Comment: No. It is not working. Website going down. Tell another way

Comment: All website down. 500 Error on admin pannel.  Website frontend is not showing

Comment: your magento version?

Comment: Date is not showing correct only on Manage customer, but when i click on customer detail then it is showing correct date

Comment: try to update your file by https://github.com/speedupmate/Magento-CE-Mirror/blob/e113f5be413f7e28253d9ac9aced3422ca88b491/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/Backend/Time/Created.php

Comment: I changed my code with this one. but no effect. Actually i found the issue but i don't know how to solve it. I have uploaded third party extenstion to enable delete order functionality. After installing this extention the time view change in manage customer. But it is showing correct on customer detail.     Third party extention is  http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/delete-orders-6.html

Comment: check with disabling the extension, still face that issue?

Comment: yes. i have disabled this extention .Still issue is there

Comment: so its not because of that extension

Comment: Actually i have two webiste. One is staging and another is onn live. When i checked my staging website then it is showin correct values then i installed that extention then that values is not coming correct now. So that's why i am saying this issue is coming from that extention. Will you please tell me how can i enable previous files

Comment: Try to clean your cache

Comment: do one thing if you still with that. replace your core magento files with the fresh one.

Comment: Which file i have to replace with freshonne? Any suggested folder

Comment: Which folder i have to replaced with freshone ? please tell me

Comment: Same issue still there

Comment: have you check you DB what the value of date is there?